# How to remove inputmask when an ajax form is submitted as FromData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-inputmask

It happens that my ajax form has a file upload input, and therefore I have to submit it with an `FormData` instead of a simple `.serialize()`. Then I found the `autoUnmask` on my jquery.inputmask no long effective.

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/btqtnumL/1/

When the form is submitted, the result from `.serialize()` has a value with input mask removed. But the result from `FormData()` still shows the mask.

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cost"
>
> 1,000

How can we remove the mask in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to get unmasked value from input, use inputmask('unmaskedvalue') [(here is a reference)](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#unmaskedvalue).

One way is to rename the input element to something like masked-cost and then use [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method.

```
<input name="masked-cost" .... />
```

In javascript you can do something like this

```
var formData = new FormData($form[0]);
formData.append('cost', $('input[name="masked-cost"]').inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
```

On the server side you can retrieve the cost variable with unmasked value.

FormData would look something like this

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryMHLOLWal6cTPLuBG Content-Disposition: form-data; name="masked-cost"
>
> 1,000
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryMHLOLWal6cTPLuBG Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cost"
>
> 1000

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/btqtnumL/2/**

Comment: So your answer means there is no convenient setting to automatically remove the mask, isn't it?

Comment: AFAIK, I dont think there is a way to *automatically* remove it especially when using FormData because inputmask library will take care if $.serialize is used.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an alternative way.

We can use jquery `.val()` to obtain the value without its mask.

```
$.each($('[data-mask="integer"]'), function (idx) {
    var input = $('[data-mask="integer"]')[idx];
    var actualValue = $(input).val();
    $(input).val(actualValue);
});
```

Then we can have the data for ajax with `$form.serialize()`.

In this way, we avoid the use of `FormData` api.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. In your javascript Use the string's .replace method with a regex of \D, which is a shorthand character class that matches all non-digits. So Steps are:

get value of input mask field.

```
 var number = $("#your_field_id").val();
```

now use .replace method with a regex of \D

```
number =  number.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

***Keep in mind its just a technique and above codes work only for number. According to your requirement use regular expression.*** more https://regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

Just remove inputmask before FormData.

```
$('#form_id :input').inputmask('remove');
data = new FormData($('#form_id'));
```